# A simple socket in python troubles

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

Am new to the field of network programming, so i thought sockets would be a good place to start. I made a simple one but it keeps throwing back an error.

this is the error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mbp/Desktop/python user files/Untitled.py", line 3, in <module>
   client_socket.connect(('localhost', 5000))
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
   return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

the serve

```
import socket
import os
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host=socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
port=12345
s.bind((host,port))

s.listen(5)
print host
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     
   print 'Got connection from', addr
   c.send('Thank you for connecting')
   c.close()
```

the client

```
import socket
import os     

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)        
host = '192.168.0.10' 
port = 12345                

s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close
```

Its only after i run the client that i get the error. Also is it much to run it on the command prompt

Comment: the client and the serve are in the same machine. i just want it to confirm the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a simple command server:
if you run the server code and then run the client you will be able to type in the client and send to the server. if you type TIME you will get from the server a respons which contains a string that has the date of today and the other commands work in the same way. if you type EXIT it will close the connection and will send from the server the string closing to the client

server:

```
import socket
import random
from datetime import date


server_socket = socket.socket()                           # new socket object
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8820))                     # empty bind (will connect to a real ip later)

server_socket.listen(1)                                   # see if any client is trying to connect

(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()  # accept the connection
while True: # main server loop
    client_cmd = client_socket.recv(1024)                 # recive user input from client
    # check waht command was entered
    if client_cmd == "TIME":
        client_socket.send(str(date.today()))             # send the date
    elif client_cmd == "NAME":
        client_socket.send("best server ever")            # send this text
    elif client_cmd == "RAND":
        client_socket.send(str(random.randrange(1,11,1))) # send this randomly generated number
    elif client_cmd == "EXIT":
        client_socket.send("closing")
        client_socket.close()                             # close the connection with the client
        server_socket.close()                             # close the server
        break
    else :
        client_socket.send("there was an error in the commend sent")

client_socket.close()                                     # just in case try to close again
server_socket.close()                                     # just in case try to close again
```

client:

```
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket()                    # new socket object
client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8820))         # connect to the server on port 8820, the ip '127.0.0.1' is special because it will always refer to your own computer

while True:
    try:
        print "please enter a commend"
        print "TIME - request the current time"
        print "NAME - request the name of the server"
        print "RAND - request a random number"
        print "EXIT - request to disconnect the sockets"
        cmd = raw_input("please enter your name") # user input

        client_socket.send(cmd)                   # send the string to the server

        data = client_socket.recv(1024)           # recive server output
        print "the server sent: " + data          # print that data from the server
        print
        if data == "closing":
            break
    except:
        print "closing server"
        break

client_socket.close()                             # close the connection with the server
```

Comment: Thank you very much. should I use the Terminal or run as it is?

Comment: Well you can run it anyway you like to but i recommend downloading PyCharm https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows and then all you need to do i order to run a program is to right click the file with the code in it and click run. make sure to configure your interpreter settings to 2.7.x in File -> Settings -> Project: "project name" -> Project Interpreter.

Comment: I have PyCharm. Everything works like charm now. I  understand sockets better now.thanx

Comment: happy to help, I was a begginer in python 6 monthes ago myself so i know how hard it can be grasping the basics

Answer (score 1):

What server are you connecting to? the server needs to have a `server_socket.accept()` in the code to accept the connecting. from only looking at your client it is hard to tell.

in order to help you i will attach a multy client chat that i wrote in python maybe you can learn some python from it it has threading and multy client socket connection if this is too much for you i have something  bit more basic just let me know with a comment

server :

```
import socket
import select
import thread
import random
from datetime import date

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8820))

server_socket.listen(5)

open_client_sockets = []
open_client_sockets_with_name = []
message_to_send = []

new_name = "new"

# recives a client socket and finds it in the list of open client sockets and returns its name
def find_name_by_socket(current_socket):
    for client_and_name in open_client_sockets_with_name:
        (client_address, client_name) = client_and_name
        if client_address == current_socket:
            return client_name 

# this function takes a commend, executes it and send the result to the client
def execute(cmd):
    if cmd == "DATE":
        current_socket.send(str(date.today()))
    elif cmd == "NAME":
        current_socket.send("best server ever")
    elif cmd == "RAND":
        current_socket.send(str(random.randrange(1,11,1)))
    elif cmd == "EXIT":
        current_socket.send("closing")
        open_client_sockets.remove(current_socket)
        open_client_sockets_with_name.remove((current_socket, find_name_by_socket(current_socket)))
        current_socket.close()
    else :
        current_socket.send("there was an error in the commend sent")

def send_waiting_message(wlist):
    # sends the message that needs to be sent
    for message in message_to_send:
        (client_socket, name, data) = message

        if data[0] != '`':
            print name + ": " + data
            for client in wlist:
                if client_socket != client:
                    client.send(name + ": " + data)
        else: # this will execute a command and not print it
            print "executing... " + data[1:]
            execute(data[1:])
        message_to_send.remove(message)

while True:
    '''
    rlist, sockets that you can read from
    wlist, sockets that you can send to
    xlist, sockets that send errors '''
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select( [server_socket] + open_client_sockets,open_client_sockets , [] )
    for current_socket in rlist:
        if current_socket is server_socket:
            (new_socket, address) = server_socket.accept()
            new_name = new_socket.recv(1024)
            print new_name + " connected"
            open_client_sockets.append(new_socket)
            open_client_sockets_with_name.append((new_socket, new_name))
        else:
            data = current_socket.recv(1024)
            if data == "":
                try:
                    open_client_sockets.remove(current_socket)
                    open_client_sockets_with_name.remove((current_socket, find_name_by_socket(current_socket)))
                except:
                    print "error"
                print "connection with client closed"
            else:

                message_to_send.append((current_socket, str(find_name_by_socket(current_socket)) ,  str(data)))

    send_waiting_message(wlist)

server_socket.close()
```

client:

```
import socket
import threading
global msg

# recives input from the server
def recv():
    while True:
        try: # try to recive that data the the server is sending
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)
            print data
        except: # the connection is closed
            return

# send user input to the server
def send():
    while True: # store what the user wrote in the global variable msg and send it to the server
        msg = raw_input("--- ")
        client_socket.send(msg)
        if msg == "`EXIT":
            client_socket.close()
            return

name = raw_input("enter your name ")
print "use ` to enter a commend"

try:
    client_socket = socket.socket()             # new socket
    client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8820))  # connect to the server
    client_socket.send(name)                    # send the name to the server

    # since receving the server's output and sending the user's input uses blocking functions it is required to run them in a separate thread
    thread_send = threading.Thread(target = send) # creates the thread in charge of sending user input
    thread_recv = threading.Thread(target = recv) # creates the thread in charge of reciving server output

    thread_recv.start() # starts the thread
    thread_send.start() # starts the thread
except:
    print "an error occurred in the main function"
    client_socket.close()
```

Comment: thanks, the client and the serve are my pc, IOW they are the same

Comment: that is not what i asked, the client and the server RUN on your pc but they are two different pages of code, as it is not possible that the client and the server will be written in the same file they need to be separate and run separately. I need to see the code of the server in order to help fix the initial problem

Comment: now i see it sorry i missed it the first time i read your post (stupid dyslexia). I think yo u need to add () around your 11th line btw (c, addr) = s.accept()

Comment: still throwing the same error. could you do me a favor please and send a simple socket for only confirming the connection, from which i can play around it.

Comment: will do i am just adding better comments to it so you can understand

Answer (score 1):

The server you're starting doesn't have the address `192.168.0.10`, rather it is local host. See the `localhost` address printed when you run `server.py`. Update the host variable to that address in `client.py` which will fix the issue.

Comment: @mohamedurrdan Can you provide more info?

Comment: I used the ip i got from localhost  and used it in the client file as you suggested  but am still getting the same error message

Comment: @mohamedurrdan it works for me without any changes except for that.